# How to delete :active with touchend

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, touch-event

Is it possible to delete the active state at touchend?
I want to style the active state of a link just by tapping on it. While scrolling in my mobile device each item I touch will get the :active state, of course. So after scrolling all the elements are highlighted.
I don't want to have a DOM manipulation with .active-classes I just want to delete the active state after scrolling - is this possible?

```
a:active {
    background-color:blue;
}

$ctx.on("touchend", '.base a', function () {
    //removeActiveState
});
```

**EDIT:**

I want to have this - but not with classes:

```
var activeSelector =  ".base a";   
$(document)
        .on("click mousedown touchstart", activeSelector, function () {
            $(this).addClass("active");
        })
        .on("mouseup mouseleave touchend", activeSelector, function () {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
```

Comment: Why don't you use `@media` to disable the `:active` for mobile devices (handhelds) or devices with lower resolution? Pro: no JS needed

Comment: I need the :active state - it should just be cleared after scrolling (I just want to have it blue by tapping on it)

Answer (score -1):

Here's your code w/o CSS classes.

```
var activeSelector =  ".base a";   
$(document)
    .on("click mousedown touchstart", activeSelector, function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    })
    .on("mouseup mouseleave touchend", activeSelector, function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white'); // or whatever color you want
    });
```